# How to play sound one by one without waiting in while loop in python?

Tags: python, audio

Like the following:(sounds are played if some condition is satisfied, so sounds are played with little interval and it will stop satisfying the condition after playing)

```py
while True:
    ......
    if condition:
        play different mp3 files
        condition = False
    ......
```

I've tried:
1.using playsound(), but if block=True, it will cost time to finish playing and the program is frozen, else if block=False, all sounds are played at the same time so I can't hear then one by one.
2.using thread with playsound's block=True option. And all sounds still overlapped.

Any solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to show your code, so that it will help in better understanding the situation.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I think the information is enough since other code is completely off the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [VLC MediaPlayer](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/) library to play your sounds. Uou can use the is_playing() method to check whether the sound you want to play is still playing. If not, you could then start the next sound.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find isPlaying() method. Could you please explain?

Comment: Found that function which is called is_playing(). Thanks anyway!